# Problem installing wine on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-netbook, live-cd

I have a problem with installing wine into my netbook running ubuntu 12.04, it says that I need to insert the installation CD, but i installed ubuntu through my USB pendrive. How can I do for installing it?

Comment: How are you trying to install wine? "sudo apt-get install wine" right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit `gksu gedit /etc/apt/source.list`

and remove any lines that start with `deb cdrom:` like so

`deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin - Alpha amd64 (20120321)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/`

then save that file and then run `sudo apt-get update` (you may have to close software center for this command to run correctly)

and then try again

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sudo apt-get install wine`, you may get the old version of wine.

It is recommended to use the sources at PPA.

The try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install wine`

May this would help you.